# How can I call a .sh script from Django, considering permissions?

Tags: django, bash, ubuntu, github, permissions

Using, Django I would like to be able to pull changes from a github repository using a view to a development server for testing. This is on the ubuntu operating system, and I am using the Apache webserver.

I've made a small `.sh` script called `gitpull.sh`. The contents of this file are:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/myrepo
env -i /usr/bin/git pull origin master
```

The permissions on this file are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   64 Mar 10 01:19 gitpull.sh
```

If I create a python shell, I can run this using the following command:

```
import os
os.system('/home/myrepo/gitpull.sh')
```

This works fine, and the repository pulls the most recent changes. I've also created a Django view that does the following:

```
import os
def hook(request):       

    os.system('/home/courb/gitpull.sh')

    template = loader.get_template('git.html')
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # Return output objects with template
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The problem I am having is that it is not pulling from the repository as I expected. I think it must be a permissions issue, but I thought apache/Django were part of the `www-data` group.

I did also try to use gitPython in the following way

```
import git
g = git.cmd.Git('/home/myrepo/')
g.pull()
```

but I had an error message about the connection being terminated. I thought the `.sh` script might be an easier way to fix this problem.

Comment: What's the error thrown on your view when trying to use the script? What type of authentication do you use against your github repo? If you're using ssh, then it may have to do with the user running the pull (www-data) not having it's pub ssh key registered on your github account...

Comment: I'm using ssh, but with a blank passphrase (none is required when I run this from python shell). No error thrown as far as I can tell (or I don't know where to look).

Comment: `I'm using ssh, but with a blank passphrase` yeah, but you're talking about *your current user*, which is not the same user that your webserver uses. Django is being run by the apache user (www-data), which haves *its own ssh key* (or not, depends in if one was created for him), and that may be causing the authentication against github to fail.

Comment: hmm, how do I check if `www-data` has it's own ssh key?

Comment: Assumming that `www-data` home directory is `/var/www` (it usually is), there should be a `.ssh` directory with the ssh key files inside (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`). If they are not there, you can create one doing `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa` and import the pub key as you should have done with your user ssh key, or you may copy your own priv key (`.ssh/id_rsa` on your home directory) to avoid importing another key (your apache user would authenticate as if it were your user).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In my local dir, I ran the following `cp .ssh/id_rsa /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa` and then tried again but it did not work. Is that the correct way to give apache my key?

Comment: Yes, that should have copied your ssh private key to the apache user home. The only thing that I can think of that you may be missing is changing the ownership of the `.ssh` folder and the `id_rsa` file to the apache user. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: currently, the settings for `www` are `drwx--S---  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 10 13:15 .ssh` I think that means apache can use the files? I'm learning about permissions at the moment though, so I might have missed something.

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Try running `sudo -u www-data yourscript.sh` to see what happens.

Comment: Just a note of caution. If you are automatically pulling code from github, please use deployment keys for the account running Django/Apache. Don't use account ssh keys. Image if you deploy your django app by using git hooks, then if your server gets compromised, malicious party will be able to push bad code to the repo, hence deploy bad code. Deployment keys are great because they allow you to pull code without password however do not allow anything to be pushed.

Comment: @asermax hmm, that command gave the result `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` At least that helps identify where it is not working, but not sure what I should do to fix it.